# The Academia logo is missing in chat.stackexchange.com

Tags: bug, chat, design, logo

When you visit the site specific chat site for [Academia](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms?tab=site&sort=active&host=academia.stackexchange.com) the logo seems to be missing on the cdn.

This is the html surrounding that image:

```
<div id="hlogo">
     <div id="header-logo">    
         <a href="http://academia.stackexchange.com" title="Academia">
            <img style="max-width:150px"
                 src="//cdn.sstatic.net/academia/img/logo.png?v=c5" 
                 alt="Academia">
         </a>
     </div>
</div>
```

The img tag expects to find the file [here](http://cdn.sstatic.net/academia/img/logo.png?v=c5) but that gives me an 404 error.

Can the logo be deployed to that location as well?